# Nested for-loops and their formats

Tags: arrays, python-2.7, loops, for-loop

I am using Python 2.7. From previous posts, I am learning Python and I have moved from arrays and now I am working on loops. I am also trying to work with operations using arrays.

```
 A1 = np.random.random_integers(35, size=(10.,5.))

 A = np.array(A1)

 B1 = np.random.random_integers(68, size=(10.,5.))

 B = np.array(B1)

 D = np.zeros(10,5) #array has 10 rows and 5 columns filled with zeros to give me the array size I want
 for j in range (1,5):
     for k in range (1,5):
          D[j,k] = 0
          for el in range (1,10):
               D[j,k] = D[j,k] + A[j] * B[k]
```

The error I am getting is : setting an array element with a sequence

Is my formatting incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because A, B and D are all 2D arrays, then D[j,k]
is a single element, while A[j] (the same as A[j,:]) is a 1D array which, in this case, has 5 elements. Similar for B[k] = B[k,:], i.e. also a 5 element array.
A[j] * B[k] is therefore also five element array, which can not be stored in the place of a single element, and you therefore get the error: setting an array element with a sequence.

If you want to select single elements from A and B, then the last line should be

```
    D[j,k] = D[j,k] + A[j,k] * B[j,k]
```

Some further comments on your code:

```
    # A is already a numpy array, so 'A = np.array(A1)' is redundant and can be omitted
    A = np.random.random_integers(35, size=(10.,5.))

    # Same as above                
    B = np.random.random_integers(68, size=(10.,5.))

    D = np.zeros([10,5]) # This is the correct syntax for creating a 2D array with the np.zeros() function
    for j in range(1,5):  
        for k in range(1,5):
             # D[j,k] = 0   You have already defined D to be zero for all elements with the np.zeros function, so there is no need to do it again
             for el in range(1,75):
                  D[j,k] = D[j,k] + A[j] * B[k]
```

EDIT:
Well, I do not have enough reputation to comment on your post @Caroline.py, so I will do it here instead:

First of all, remember that python uses zero indexing, so 'range(1,5)' gives you '[1,2,3,4]', which means that you would not reach the first index, i.e. index 0. Thus you would probably want to use 'range(0,5)', which is the same as just 'range(5)', instead.

I can see that you changed the el range from 75 to 10. If you don't use el to anything, it just means that you add perform the last line 10 times.

I don't know what you want to do, but if you want to store the multiple of A and B in D, then this should be right:

```
    for j in range(10):  
        for k in range(5):
              D[j,k] = A[j,k] * B[j,k]
```

or just

```
    D = A * B
```